# Why does it say the element is null?

Tags: javascript

```
<p id = "a" onclick = "doThis()">ABCD</p>
function doThis() {
    output = document.getElementById("a");
    alert(output.innerHTML);
    //alert should say ABCD//
}
```

The above code works fine. Now, my problem is, I have multiple id's, and I want to change them dynamically. I tried doing this by adding parameters to doThis(); it works fine, but when I set up temp = document.getElementById(stringId) and attempt to alert the innerHTML, the console gives me an error saying it cannot read innerHTML, and that temp is null. How come it doesn't work like the above?

```
<p id = "a" onclick = "doThis(a)">ABCD</p>
<p id = "b" onclick = "doThis(b)">EFGH</p>
function doThis(x) {
    theId = '"' + x + '"';
    output = document.getElementById(theId);
    //here I used alert to test it. Both output and it's innerHTML is "null". Why isn't the innerHTML ABCD or EFGH?//
```

Comment: I've tried your methods, but the console still gives me TypeError: cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your on click to `"doThis('a')"` and then your code will work.  Right now you are not passing in a string, which is what `getElementById` is expecting.

```js
function doThis(x) {
  output = document.getElementById(x);
  console.log(output.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<p id="a" onclick="doThis('a')">ABCD</p>
<p id="b" onclick="doThis('b')">EFGH</p>
```

Here is a snippet showing what you are passing in in your question:

```js
function doThis(x) {
  console.log(typeof(x));
}
```

```html
<p id = "a" onclick = "doThis(a)">ABCD</p>
<p id = "b" onclick = "doThis(b)">EFGH</p>
```

As you can see, you are passing an object, not a string.

Comment: `typeof` is your friend! Happy programming!

Answer (score 1):

Because the name of the Id isn't `"a"` it's `a`

Try something like this instead:

```
theId = x;
```

Comment: But if I alert theId, it gives me "a". Is that not a string? And if it is, can't I use it as the id?

Comment: @idontknowanygoodusernames If you pass in a string, the data type is a string. You don't need to put quotes around it to turn it into a string.

Comment: Also, when you call doThis(...) you need to pass in a string which you are not doing. doThis('a') instead of doThis(a)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p id = "a" onclick = "doThis('a')">ABCD</p>
<p id = "b" onclick = "doThis('b')">EFGH</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doThis(x) {
    theId = '"' + x + '"';
    output = document.getElementById(theId);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id in quotes 
`doThis('a')`

```js
function doThis(x) {
  alert(document.getElementById(x).innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<p id="a" onclick="doThis('a')">ABCD</p>
<p id="b" onclick="doThis('b')">EFGH</p>
```